# indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript

I' am currently working with the following code. In the console it's throwing

> Uncaught TypeError: TotalAccountBalance.indexOf is not a function

I don't know what else to do. Searching didn't help much.

```
var CurrentPreservedBalance, CurrentGeneralAccountBalance, TotalAccountBalance;
    CurrentPreservedBalance = '20.56';
    CurrentGeneralAccountBalance = '20.56';
    if( CurrentPreservedBalance && CurrentGeneralAccountBalance ){
        TotalAccountBalance = +CurrentPreservedBalance + +CurrentGeneralAccountBalance;
        console.log( TotalAccountBalance.indexOf('.') );
    } else {
        $('#total-fnpf-account-balance').val('$0.00');
        $('#total-account-balance').val('$0.00');
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of one of those pluses `+CurrentPreservedBalance + +CurrentGeneralAccountBalance;` in the middle. Then `TotalAccountBalance.` should work. and that plus in the front as well. Also, remove the quotes from '20.56'

Comment: BTW, why would you need the indexOf the decimal for?

Comment: @zer00ne my client has this stupid requirement which I even don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Ah, say no more, many clients indeed have moments of stupidity of great magnitudes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is a method of Strings, not Numbers.

```
console.log( TotalAccountBalance.toString().indexOf('.') );
```

Comment: Also in case if there is some `null` scenario for `TotalAccountBalance` it could be converted like this to avoid error: `console.log( String(TotalAccountBalance).indexOf('.') );`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> TotalAccountBalance = +CurrentPreservedBalance + +CurrentGeneralAccountBalance;
> ```

`TotalAccountBalance` is the result of taking two numbers (we know they are numbers because you used the unary plus operator to convert them) and **adding** them together. This is another number.

`indexOf` is a method that you find on **strings** not **numbers**.

You could convert to a string:

```
(TotalAccountBalance + "").indexOf('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TotalAccountBalance = +CurrentPreservedBalance + +CurrentGeneralAccountBalance;
```

The [unary plus operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) convert the strings into numbers; this is obviously desirable behaviour in order to get the correct mathematical result.

If you then want to use a string function (e.g. [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)), you need to convert back to a string:

```
console.log( ("" + TotalAccountBalance).indexOf('.') );
```